# Multiple buttonclick on TaskOnClick C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for the first time I'm working with Unity. In the canvas I have two buttons. The next en previous button.

How to handle those buttons, one button is only working?

```
public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Button mNextButton;
public Button mPrevButton;
public GameObject stap1;
public GameObject stap2;

void Start()
 {
    mNextButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    mPrevButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
 }

void TaskOnClick()
 {
    //Next button
    stap1.SetActive(false);
    stap2.SetActive(true);

    //Previous button
    stap1.SetActive(true);
    stap2.SetActive(false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Both buttons are calling one function and there is no way to tell which button is clicked. See the answer from the duplicated question for a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer, solved it!